# Average of conditional probabilities and co-occurance

Tags: probability, expectation, average, means

I have a few measures based on probabilities. I am looking for a way to compute their central tendencies / summaries / averages.

Let's say that, I have 2 people: `A` and `B`. I have probabilities that they were late to work month-over-month, calculated from some actual or sample data. Let each row in the table below represent each month. Now, I can calculate conditional probabilities (`P(B/A)` and `P(A/B)`) and degree of co-occurrence (`P(B/A) / P(B)` or `P(A/B) / P(A)` or `P(A n B) / (P(A)P(B))`).

```
         P(A)    P(B)    P(A n B)    P(B/A)    P(A/B)   P(A n B)/(P(A)P(B))
month1   0.3     0.2     0.1         0.333     0.5            1.667
month2   0.2     0.25    0.13        0.65      0.52           2.6
month3   0.18    0.22    0.16        0.889     0.727          4.04
```

Since we used sample data (or assumed that there are exactly the same number of working days each month), we can use arithmetic mean for `P(A)`, `P(B)` and `P(A n B)`. Beyond that, it's not clear what is the right 'average'. The following table represents arithmetic mean of each of the columns from the above table:

```
         P(A)    P(B)    P(A n B)    P(B/A)    P(A/B)   P(A n B)/(P(A)P(B))
Average  0.227   0.223   0.13        0.624     0.582          2.769
```

These numbers are inconsistent. If I performed conditional probability and co-occurrence calculations from the probabilities, I would get `P(B/A) = 0.573`, `P(A/B) = 0.583`, and `P(A n B)/(P(A)P(B)) = 2.572`. The results look vastly different. Geometric mean leads to similar problems. **Is there a principled way to calculate 'average' of conditional probabilities and degree of co-occurrences without having to convert them back to original data?**

Also note, if this is easy to calculate, I am looking to also find central tendency of `(P(A n B) - P(A)P(B)) / P(A)`, which is defined as degree of implication and is a ratio metric that ranges between [-1, 1].

Comment: Assuming months are similar (e.g. in terms of numbers of days), you could just use the averages for $P(A), P(B), P(A \cap B)$ and work out the others from there such as $P(B \mid A) \approx 0.57$ and $P(A \mid B) \approx 0.58$

Comment: @Henry, I have already performed those calculations in the question, but I would prefer to not have to recompute from P(A), P(B), P(A∩B) every time. I intend to retain only degree of co-occurrences and implications for each month.